# FFmpeg - Calculating with Framerate?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame-rate, ffmpeg-php

I have to cut my video exactly. This video could have 25fps or 30fps (i dont know). 
is there a Variable in ffmpeg for the framerate so i could calculate on which frame i had to Cut? I only have the seconds of my video. 
something like this (for example 80sec video):

vf "fade=in:0:12,fade=out:(80*r):12"

```
-vf "fade=in:0:12,fade=out:2500:12"
```

Comment: You can directly reference [time](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the fade in start time and duration time in addition to start frame and frame duration.

```
-vf "fade=in:st=0.0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=75.5:d=0.5"
```

Comment: Thanks !that better then handle Framerates

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg comes installed with

```
ffprobe
```

which shows stats of given media file ... here is an example

```
ffprobe "The Fourth Phase of Water - Dr. Gerald Pollack at TEDxGuelphU-i-T7tCMUDXU.mp4"

... here is output of above command

ffprobe version N-86279-gac8dfcbd89 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 20170406
  configuration: 
  libavutil      55. 63.100 / 55. 63.100
  libavcodec     57. 96.101 / 57. 96.101
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 90.100 /  6. 90.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'The Fourth Phase of Water - Dr. Gerald Pollack at TEDxGuelphU-i-T7tCMUDXU.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2016-08-25T12:06:13.000000Z
  Duration: 00:24:14.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 923 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 794 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T12:06:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T12:06:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
```

so now you have both total time and fps so you can calculate total number of frames or just use time to cut your video

Comment: This was my first thought but i know that there are a few other options like "w" and "h" to read the width and height of a video without ffprobe